# Запятая в предложении "Жалею о том(,) что сделала"

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли здесь запятая: *Жалею о том что сделала*?

Comment: @АртёмЛуговой Не уверен, что правка хороша. (1) Это Вы увидели здесь придаточное предложение — и это фактически является ответом на вопрос, — а автор вопроса этого не видел. (2) Запятая не в придаточном предложении, а перед ним (в СПП).

Comment: Я лишь добавил курсив и знак вопроса. :))

Answer (score 3):

**Жалею о том, что сделала.**

Запятая ставится **в сложноподчиненном предложении** между главной и придаточной частью (после указательного местоимения О ТОМ перед союзным словом ЧТО).

Оборот с союзом (союзным словом) ЧТО может не отделяться запятой, если он является  цельным по смыслу выражением, например:  найду что делать (= найду занятие).

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=146#pp146

Answer (score 1):

**Жалею о том, что сделала.**

Запятая ставится между простыми предложениями, входящими в состав сложноподчиненного предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая нужна. Жалею о **том,** что сделала.